# Is this a data issue, or a model issue? A Keras binary classification model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, dataset, data-cleaning

I've been trying to create a binary classification model that predicts wether there will be a train delay based on the train and time. [Here is a link to the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDrhgz0CEWhMqKi36_kVgYZ5Jl5m-XPAv_9pHwnOjKQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The issue I'm having is that my accuracy goes to 94.07 in the first 5 epochs. Meanwhile, my class prediction will always be 0 and never 1.

From what I understand, this is "Accuracy Paradox". A symptom of *Class Imbalance*. To combat this, I implemented Kfold.

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True)
cvs_scores = []

for train,test in kfold.split(X,Y):

  history = model.fit(X[train],Y[train],epochs=50,batch_size=15, shuffle = False, verbose = 1)
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test],Y[test],verbose=0)

  print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1],scores[1]*100))
  cvs_scores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvs_scores),numpy.std(cvs_scores)))
```

No luck. Still had the same issue as before.

Here is how I import my data:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('MTA_DELAY_DATA_DUMP - Sheet1.csv')

X = raw_data.iloc[1:-2,0:2].dropna().values
Y = raw_data.iloc[1:-2,2:3].dropna().astype(int).values
```

My Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu',input_dim =2))
model.add(Dense(16, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8,  kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,  kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])  
history = model.fit(X,Y,epochs=150,batch_size=15, shuffle = False, verbose = 1)
```

I tried assigning class weights to balance the data out. Even manually deleting 0's in the data, but nothing seems to result in accurate predictions. Am I doing something wrong in the model, or is this simply data that cannot be utilized by machine learning?

Comment: Are you trying to predict "Result" column? That column has values 0 and 0.1. Did you want to put 1 there instead of 0.1?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pratik. Yes that's the column I'm hoping to predict. I tried making it "1" before, but it didn't make that drastic of a change. So I figured I would just leave it as "0.1"

Comment: Since you are using binary cross entropy as loss func, you want to make them 1. Otherwise $  -{(y\log(p) + (1 - y)\log(1 - p))}$ will give wrong value. It expects y to be 1 or 0. So 0.1 is definitely wrong thing to have in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problems:

1. You have classes 0 and 0.1. You want to make them 0 and 1 since the formula for the loss function 
   $$-{(y\log(p) + (1 - y)\log(1 - p))}$$
   expects $y$ to be 0 or 1.
2. `shuffle = False` why would you want to turn shuffling off?
3. The classes are unbalanced. You have ~100 examples of class 1  and ~20000 total examples. So if you just predict class of everything to be 0 you will be right (20000-100)/20000 = 99.5% times. You can try [these tricks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) and see if they help.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because of point number three. I used downsampling, and got the ratio to 1:1, making my accuracy now ~50%. I am now seeing [0,1] class predictions being made, so it's going towards the right direction! A quick follow up though: If I gather more samples, and preserve the 1:1 ratio, will my prediction accuracy increase?

Comment: Its hard to say but more data is almost always good. In theory, 1:1 data and 50% accuracy is better than random guessing. If you guessed randomly you would get only 25% accuracy. But 50% accuracy still looks suspicious. Your model might not be learning what you want. Try new things and if you get stuck post a new question. :-)

Comment: I'll see how the things go with some fresh data. I appreciate all your help! Cheers!